# trying to get my button to change text without user interaction javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

i made a button function that has a button with a word and when its clicked the definition shows. but now i'm trying to make it so that the buttons shows the definition every couple seconds with "SetInterval" without needing to be clicked and i don't know how to go about doing so can you please help.

```js
'use strict';
//below is the function for the even
$(document).ready(function() {
  //
  function salutationsHandler(evnt) {
    let box = $("#message-box");

    if (box.hasClass("hidden")) {
      box.attr("class", "");
      $(evnt.target).text("1.Salutation");
    } else {
      box.attr("class", "hidden");
      $(evnt.target).text('a greeting in words or actions');


    }

  }
  //end of function
  setInterval(salutationsHandler, 1000);

  //start of another
  function DiffidenceHandler(evnt2) {
    let box2 = $("#message-box2");

    if (box2.hasClass("hidden")) {
      box2.attr("class", "");
      $(evnt2.target).text("2.Diffidence");
    } else {
      box2.attr("class", "hidden");
      $(evnt2.target).text("the quality of being shy");
    }
    console.log(evnt2);
  }
  //lets me target id
  let salutationsGrab = $('#Salutations');
  // adds event to said id 
  // event listeners grab events from functions
  salutationsGrab.on('click', salutationsHandler);



  let DiffidenceGrab = $("#Diffidence");

  DiffidenceGrab.on("click", DiffidenceHandler);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>hello welcome to our dictionary</h1>
<h2>Click on button to reveal definition of word shown</h2>


<button id="Salutations">1.Saluation</button>
<div id="message-box"></div>
<br>
<button id="Diffidence">2.Diffidence</button>
<div id="message-box2"></div>
<br>
```

Comment: The console is your friend. `salutationsHandler` isn't an event handler, it's just a function that runs every second. You get the `box` then ignore it when setting `text`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `salutationsHandler` needs the event object generated by an event to work. Instead of calling the function directly, you can use jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to "click" the button.

```js
function salutationsHandler(evnt) {
  const box = $("#message-box");
  const target = $(evnt.target);

  if (box.hasClass("hidden")) {
    box.removeClass("hidden");
    target.text("1.Salutation");
  } else {
    box.addClass("hidden");
    target.text('a greeting in words or actions');
  }

}

let salutationsGrab = $('#Salutations');
salutationsGrab.on('click', salutationsHandler);

setInterval(() => salutationsGrab.trigger('click'), 1000);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>hello welcome to our dictionary</h1>
<h2>Click on button to reveal definition of word shown</h2>


<button id="Salutations">1.Saluation</button>
<div id="message-box">a greeting in words or actions</div>
```